# New mailbox not getting created in new macOS 10.12.1

Tags: mail.app, email, macos, imap

After I had migrated to 10.12.1, I started facing issues in creating new mailboxes in my mail account in the official Mail app. Earlier, I simply used to create a new mailbox and it used to appear immediately on the left-hand side along with other mailboxes. But now, when I create a mailbox, it asks me the Location and Name, and then nothing happens. Nowhere the mailbox is and I have a tough time to find a solution of this.

I tried creating a new folder in my email account by logging into the web interface (Squirrelmail), and it showed up as a new mailbox, but the reverse is not working.

Is this a known issue in 10.12.1? Any workaround / fix for this? I am having my own domain and using IMAP to configure the same in Mail app.

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, are you using the public release version of Sierra 10.12.0 or the developer beta of 10.12.1?

Comment: I just realised the version says 10.12.1 Beta. I don't know how it updated to this Beta version. Is this beta version causing the trouble?

Comment: It's possible there's a bug impacting account creation, yes. (Not that stable releases can't have bugs, but it's more likely in a beta.)

Comment: I updated to the stable 10.12.1 but the problem still persists. When I checked with Apple support, they said I can try creating a new user profile and check there. I am yet to do that since that looks to be a more time consuming activity.

Comment: Did you ever get a better suggestion than creating a new user profile to set up new mailboxes in Sierra 10.12.1? I'm having the same problem with new mailbox not showing up.

Comment: No, I am still facing the issue. I installed Outlook as well and create folders using that as a workaround as Apple said I have to create a new user profile and try with that to nail down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue as well, but stumbled across the answer, at least on my system. In the Mailboxes sidebar, try hovering over the name of the Mailbox within which you've tried to create new mailboxes...you should see a '+' as well as a 'Show' option appear to the right of the Mailbox name. Click 'Show' (*not* the '+'). The sub-mailboxes you've created should now appear beneath the main Mailbox.